# Testing Stateful Session Beans with Arquillian (arq-jbossas-remote)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I have several `@Stateful` SessionBeans annotated like this:

```
@Stateful
@Remote(AdminFacade.class)
public class TAdminFacadeBean implements TgAdminFacade,Serializable
{
   ...
}
```

Now I want to test them with Arquillian (1.0.0.Alpha5), but get lot's of different errors, messages vary either if the annotations are `@Stateful` or `@Stateless`, if a `@Named` is added or if there is no @Remote (and `implements` Interface).

Steps to reproduce:

- Create new maven project with
  archetype org.jboss.weld.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp:1.0.1.CR2
- You might need to set jboss.home (see
  readme.txt)
- Modify pom.xml and set profiles.profile[id=default].build.plugins.plugin[artifactId=maven-surefire-plugin].configuration.skip
  to false
- Start JBoss-6.0.0.Final
- Execute test (should pass): `mvn test -Parq-jbossas-remote`

The bean tested here ist `MemberRegistration`:

```
@Model
public class MemberRegistration
{
   ...
}
```

If you now change `@Model` to `@Stateful`, JBoss loops with stacktraces, with `@Named @Stateful` this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found.
Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact
DeployableContainer developer.
```

`@Named @Stateless`:

```
javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState
- ARJUNA-16051 thread is already associated with a transaction!
```

How can I test my `@Stateful` Beans with Arquillian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over and over again working in this issue I figured out the solution. Even I hate answering my own question I hope this can help somebody in the future.

The annotation for the `@Stateful` session bean (at the top of the question) are correct and stay the same. In the Arquillian test case the bean was originally injected with

```
@Inject MemberRegistration memberRegistration;
```

This works with `@Model` beans but not with `@Stateful` session beans and a `@Remote` interface. It seems this kind of beans must be injected with

```
@EJB private AdminFacade adminBean;
```

See [What is the difference between @Inject and @EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889767)