# Should I use @EJB or @Inject

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I have found this question: [What is the difference between @Inject and @EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889767/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-ejb) but I did not get any wiser. I have not done Java EE before nor do I have experience with dependency injection so I do not understand what I should use?

Is `@EJB` an old way of injecting? Is the injection done by the EJB container when using this annotation while using `@Inject` use the new CDI framework? Is that the difference and should I be using `@Inject` instead of `@EJB` if this is the case?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The `@EJB` is used to inject EJB's only and is available for quite some time now. `@Inject` can inject any managed bean and is a part of the new CDI specification (since Java EE 6).

In simple cases you can simply change `@EJB` to `@Inject`. In more advanced cases (e.g. when you heavily depend on `@EJB`'s attributes like `beanName`, `lookup` or `beanInterface`) than in order to use `@Inject` you would need to define a `@Producer` field or method.

These resources might be helpful to understand the differences between `@EJB` and `@Produces` and how to get the best of them:

Antonio Goncalves' blog:
[CDI Part I](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/injection-with-cdi-part-i/)
[CDI Part II](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/injection-with-cdi-part-ii/)
[CDI Part III](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/injection-with-cdi-part-iii/)

JBoss Weld documentation:
[CDI and the Java EE ecosystem](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/part4.html)

StackOverflow:
[Inject @EJB bean based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920123/inject-ejb-bean-based-on-conditions/7923159#7923159)

Comment: why does `@EJB` work for circular injection (one singleton bean and another bean needing a reference to each other)? (with reference to my answer below - i am not sure if i am doing the right thing by switching to `@EJB`)

Comment: because you're not injecting the implementation, but a proxy that interposes on the implementation.  because of this, you get the advantages of "late binding" and other container features.

Answer (score 38):

`@Inject` can inject any bean, while `@EJB` can only inject EJBs. You can use either to inject EJBs, but I'd prefer `@Inject` everywhere.

Comment: What exactly makes the injection when we use @Inject? The JavaEE container? Can it inject POJO 's?

Comment: with CDI it's the CDI container (bundled in the JavaEE container)

Answer (score 16):

**Update:** This answer may be incorrect or out of date. Please see comments for details.

I switched from `@Inject` to `@EJB` because `@EJB` allows circular injection whereas `@Inject` pukes on it.

Details: I needed `@PostConstruct` to call an `@Asynchronous` method but it would do so synchronously. The only way to make the asynchronous call was to have the original call a method of another bean and have it call back the method of the original bean. To do this each bean needed a reference to the other -- thus circular. `@Inject` failed for this task whereas `@EJB` worked.

Comment: @MartijnBurger I don't have the code handy, nor a Java EE environment handy. Just create 2 Java classes and `@Inject` them into each other's public fields. If that works then my answer is wrong. If that does not work, then my answer is correct so far. Next change the `@Inject` to `@EJB` (and possibly annotate the classes themselves? I forget.). Then the cyclic mutual injection should work fine. That's why I switched from `@Inject` to `@EJB`. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I created two pojo's and injected the pojo's into each other. Works without problems in my config (WildFly 8.2 = CDI 1.2)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnBurger, I'll confirm that, and in the meanwhile add a note of caution to my answer.

Comment: No exactly sure what you wanted to achieve, but this probably does exactly what you wanted and without a circular dependency. http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/async-postconstruct/README.html. Also asynchronous CDI events could be a cleaner way to go (depending on the requirements).

Answer (score 12):

Here is a good discussion on the topic.  Gavin King recommends @Inject over @EJB for non remote EJBs.

http://www.seamframework.org/107780.lace

or

https://web.archive.org/web/20140812065624/http://www.seamframework.org/107780.lace

> Re: Injecting with @EJB or @Inject?
>
> 26. Nov 2009, 20:48 America/New_York | Link Gavin King
>
> That error is very strange, since EJB local references should always
>   be serializable. Bug in glassfish, perhaps?
>
> Basically, @Inject is always better, since:
>
> ```
> it is more typesafe,
> it supports @Alternatives, and
> it is aware of the scope of the injected object.
> ```
>
> I recommend against the use of @EJB except for declaring references to
>   remote EJBs.

and

> Re: Injecting with @EJB or @Inject?
>
> 29. Nov 2009, 17:42 America/New_York | Link Gavin King
>
>     Does it mean @EJB better with remote EJBs?
>
> For a remote EJB, we can't declare metadata like qualifiers,
>   @Alternative, etc, on the bean class, since the client simply isn't
>   going to have access to that metadata. Furthermore, some additional
>   metadata must be specified that we don't need for the local case
>   (global JNDI name of whatever). So all that stuff needs to go
>   somewhere else: namely the @Produces declaration.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way this answer would be valuable even now when the link is dead.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140812065624/http://www.seamframework.org/107780.lace

Answer (score 5):

It may also be usefull to understand the difference in term of Session Bean Identity when using @EJB and @Inject.
According to the specifications the following code will always be `true`:

```
@EJB Cart cart1;
@EJB Cart cart2;
… if (cart1.equals(cart2)) { // this test must return true ...}
```

Using @Inject instead of @EJB there is not the same.

see also [stateless session beans identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460383/stateless-session-beans-identity-with-ejb-and-inject) for further info

Answer (score 0):

Injection already existed in Java EE 5 with the @Resource, @PersistentUnit or @EJB annotations, for example.
But it was limited to certain resources (datasource, EJB . . .) and into certain components (Servlets, EJBs, JSF backing
bean . . .). With CDI you can inject nearly anything anywhere thanks to the @Inject annotation.

Answer (score 0):

when you heavily depend on @EJB's attributes like beanName, lookup or beanInterface) than in order to use @Inject you would need to define a @Producer field or method.

Answer (score 0):

@Inject is a documented annotation, so IDEA knows how to process it and you can see a different colours in a code. @EJB - no.

Answer (score -1):

use @EBJ with EJB's.  This is for creating a separated business logic layer that is independent of the types of interfaces (Tiered Applications).

This (used correctly) allows the business logic to be modified and deployed separately from the (multiple) user-interface applications without loss of availability.