# JSF / Hibernate / Rest, Why Nullpointer ?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jsf

I try to make an rest service based on JSF and hibernate. The Database is specified in the Jboss standalone.xml.
But the Url that should give me an MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON gives me a Nullpointer instead. 
**de.bht.server/rest/resource/json**

```
package de.bht.server.jax;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.database.Service;
import com.database.SurveyQuestion;

    @Path("/resource")
    public class Resource {

        @Inject
        private Service service;

        // This method is called if Json request
        @GET
        @Path("/json")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<SurveyQuestion> getJson() {
            System.out.println("Resource: " + service);
            return service.getAllQuestions();
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/test")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<SurveyQuestion> getTestJson() {

            ArrayList<SurveyQuestion> list = new ArrayList<SurveyQuestion>();
            SurveyQuestion sq = new SurveyQuestion();

            sq.setFreetext(true);
            sq.setId(5l);
            sq.setIdx(6);
            sq.setMandatory(true);
            sq.setMultiplechoice(true);
            sq.setSheet_id(7l);
            sq.setTitle("What's app?");

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                list.add(sq);

            return list;
        }
    }
```

My RestApplication

```
package de.bht.server.jax;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

}
```

My Inject service

```
package com.database;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Stateless
public class Service {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<SurveyQuestion> getAllQuestions() {
        System.out.println("Service: " + em);
        final Query query = this.em.createNamedQuery("getWholeTable");

        System.out.println("ServicePrint: " + query);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

And the Pojo I try to map

```
package com.database;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "getWholeTable", query = "select t from SurveyQuestion t")
@Table(name = "survey_question", schema = "tnt_test")
public class SurveyQuestion implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4571690522451469184L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "freetext")
    private boolean freetext;

    @Column(name = "idx")
    private Integer idx;

    @Column(name = "mandatory")
    private boolean mandatory;

    @Column(name = "multiplechoice")
    private boolean multiplechoice;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "sheet_id")
    private Long sheet_id;

    public SurveyQuestion() {

    }

    public boolean getFreetext() {
        return freetext;
    }

    public void setFreetext(boolean freetext) {
        this.freetext = freetext;
    }

    public Integer getIdx() {
        return idx;
    }

    public void setIdx(Integer idx) {
        this.idx = idx;
    }

    public boolean getMandatory() {
        return mandatory;
    }

    public void setMandatory(boolean mandatory) {
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }

    public boolean getMultiplechoice() {
        return multiplechoice;
    }

    public void setMultiplechoice(boolean multiplechoice) {
        this.multiplechoice = multiplechoice;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getSheet_id() {
        return sheet_id;
    }

    public void setSheet_id(Long sheet_id) {
        this.sheet_id = sheet_id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SurveyQuestion ,id=" + id + ", freetext=" + freetext + ", idx="
                + idx + ", mandatory=" + mandatory + ", multiplechoice="
                + multiplechoice + ", title=" + title + ", sheet_id="
                + sheet_id;
    }

}
```

My Stacktrace

```
2013-12-25 13:12:53,075 INFO  [org.jboss.modules]  JBoss Modules version 1.1.3.GA
2013-12-25 13:12:53,310 INFO  [org.jboss.msc]  JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
2013-12-25 13:12:53,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as]  JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT "Steropes" starting
2013-12-25 13:12:54,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]  JBAS015003: Found de.bht.server.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called de.bht.server.war.dodeploy
2013-12-25 13:12:54,528 INFO  [org.xnio]  XNIO Version 3.0.6.GA
2013-12-25 13:12:54,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]  JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
2013-12-25 13:12:54,528 INFO  [org.xnio.nio]  XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.6.GA
2013-12-25 13:12:54,544 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting]  JBoss Remoting version 3.2.8.SP1
2013-12-25 13:12:54,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin]  JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
2013-12-25 13:12:54,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi]  JBAS011906: Activating OSGi Subsystem
2013-12-25 13:12:54,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming]  JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
2013-12-25 13:12:54,622 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security]  JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
2013-12-25 13:12:54,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security]  JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.13.Final
2013-12-25 13:12:54,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices]  JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
2013-12-25 13:12:54,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging]  JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.12.Final)
2013-12-25 13:12:54,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming]  JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
2013-12-25 13:12:54,809 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension]  JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2013-12-25 13:12:54,980 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]  JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.2)
2013-12-25 13:12:55,043 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig]  JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.1.0.Beta2
2013-12-25 13:12:55,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]  JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
2013-12-25 13:12:55,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]  JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Development\jboss_as\standalone\deployments
2013-12-25 13:12:55,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "de.bht.server.war"
2013-12-25 13:12:55,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting]  JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:10004
2013-12-25 13:12:55,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting]  JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4452
2013-12-25 13:12:55,950 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol]  Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8085
2013-12-25 13:12:56,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]  JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/WebappFrameworkDS]
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleConstructor$HandleAllArgsConstructor' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleConstructor$HandleNoArgsConstructor' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleConstructor$HandleRequiredArgsConstructor' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleLog$HandleCommonsLog' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleLog$HandleJulLog' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleLog$HandleLog4j2Log' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleLog$HandleLog4jLog' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleLog$HandleSlf4jLog' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.javac.handlers.HandleLog$HandleXSlf4jLog' for service type 'lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.core.Main$LicenseApp' for service type 'lombok.core.LombokApp'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.core.Main$VersionApp' for service type 'lombok.core.LombokApp'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.installer.Installer$CommandLineInstallerApp' for service type 'lombok.core.LombokApp'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.installer.Installer$CommandLineUninstallerApp' for service type 'lombok.core.LombokApp'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.installer.Installer$GraphicalInstallerApp' for service type 'lombok.core.LombokApp'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleConstructor$HandleAllArgsConstructor' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleConstructor$HandleNoArgsConstructor' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleConstructor$HandleRequiredArgsConstructor' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleLog$HandleCommonsLog' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleLog$HandleJulLog' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleLog$HandleLog4j2Log' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,665 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleLog$HandleLog4jLog' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,681 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleLog$HandleSlf4jLog' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,681 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]  JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleLog$HandleXSlf4jLog' for service type 'lombok.eclipse.EclipseAnnotationHandler'
2013-12-25 13:12:58,962 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa]  JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for database
2013-12-25 13:12:59,368 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer]  JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment de.bht.server.war
2013-12-25 13:12:59,992 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer]  JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: de.bht.server.war
2013-12-25 13:13:00,102 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version]  WELD-000900 1.1.16 (Final)
2013-12-25 13:13:00,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa]  JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'de.bht.server.war#database'
2013-12-25 13:13:00,321 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version]  HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
2013-12-25 13:13:00,321 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version]  HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.6.Final}
2013-12-25 13:13:00,336 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment]  HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2013-12-25 13:13:00,336 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment]  HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2013-12-25 13:13:00,352 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration]  HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: database
    ...]
2013-12-25 13:13:00,586 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator]  HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
2013-12-25 13:13:01,273 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]  HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2013-12-25 13:13:01,273 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder]  HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2013-12-25 13:13:01,289 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator]  HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
2013-12-25 13:13:01,289 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory]  HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2013-12-25 13:13:01,321 INFO  [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]  HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: de.bht.server.war#database.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
2013-12-25 13:13:01,321 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry]  ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Brahma' 5.1.7.Final
2013-12-25 13:13:01,461 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration]  ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform mbean server.
2013-12-25 13:13:01,477 INFO  [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]  HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: de.bht.server.war#database.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
2013-12-25 13:13:01,477 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration]  ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform mbean server.
2013-12-25 13:13:01,493 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version]  Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
2013-12-25 13:13:01,728 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration]  ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform mbean server.
2013-12-25 13:13:01,868 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator]  HHH000229: Running schema validator
2013-12-25 13:13:01,868 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator]  HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2013-12-25 13:13:01,899 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata]  HHH000261: Table found: tnt_test.survey_question
2013-12-25 13:13:01,899 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata]  HHH000037: Columns: [id, title, multiplechoice, idx, mandatory, sheet_id, freetext]
2013-12-25 13:13:02,040 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer]  JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment de.bht.server.war
2013-12-25 13:13:02,274 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.ConfigurationExtension activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,274 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exception.control.extension.ExceptionControlExtension activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,274 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.SecurityExtension activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,289 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.message.MessageBundleExtension activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,289 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exclude.extension.ExcludeExtension activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,289 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exclude.CustomProjectStageBeanFilter activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,289 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exclude.GlobalAlternative activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,289 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils]  class: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.jmx.MBeanExtension activated=true
2013-12-25 13:13:02,368 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer]  Computed the following DeltaSpike ProjectStage: Production
2013-12-25 13:13:03,554 INFO  [org.jboss.web]  JBAS018210: Register web context: /de.bht.server
2013-12-25 13:13:03,726 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config]  Mojarra 2.1.13-jbossorg-1 20120919-1641 für Kontext '/de.bht.server' wird initialisiert.
2013-12-25 13:13:07,127 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener]  Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
2013-12-25 13:13:08,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]  JBAS018559: Deployed "de.bht.server.war"
2013-12-25 13:13:08,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as]  JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9995/management
2013-12-25 13:13:08,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as]  JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9995
2013-12-25 13:13:08,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as]  JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT "Steropes" started in 15582ms - Started 204 of 288 services (83 services are passive or on-demand)
2013-12-25 13:13:15,567 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory]  Found BeanManager at java:comp/BeanManager
2013-12-25 13:13:15,567 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment]  Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class de.bht.server.jax.RestApplication
2013-12-25 13:13:15,693 INFO  [stdout]  Resource: null

2013-12-25 13:13:15,709 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/de.bht.server].[de.bht.server.jax.RestApplication]]  Servlet.service() for servlet de.bht.server.jax.RestApplication threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.bht.server.jax.Resource.getJson(Resource.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
    ... 28 more
```

It seems like

```
 @Inject
 private Service service;
```

in Resources has some problems, but why is that ? 
I'm thankful for any hints.

Comment: do you have the beans.xml at the correct location?

Comment: do I need this if my pojo isn't marked as @ManagedBean ?

Comment: yes, otherwise CDI won't work: http://www.seamframework.org/124139.lace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer for your problem is, put an empty file named [beans.xml](http://www.seamframework.org/124139.lace) into the WEB-INF folder.

Alternatively, you can annotate your service with `@EJB` instead.

See this answer for a longer explanation: [Should I use @EJB or @Inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138232/should-i-use-ejb-or-inject)

Comment: Somehow beans.xml didn't work I placed it in resources/WEB-INF, but still Nullpointer, I will give @EJB a try

Comment: Ahh nevermind sry ^^ my server has created main.webapp, there was the right location - worked thanks a lot. Now I can get further in my project at least :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but I think src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml is the correct place an not src/main/resources/WEB-INF

Comment: Yeah you're right it's src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml. I have my persistence.xml in resources so I thought that would be it :)

Comment: So, did my answer above solve your problem? If so, I would be happy if you accepted the answer, if it didn't never mind :)

Comment: Yeah it did, here you go ^^ wish you merry christmas too

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your web.xml? I had a similar problem once and it was a configuration error in the web.xml- File.

You have to declare a servlet:

```
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">

        ...
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```