# Stateless Session Beans Identity with @EJB and @Inject

Tags: ejb-3.1, java-ee-7, ejb-3.2

I have been looking into section 3.4.7.2 of the EJB3.2 specifications lately und done some tests.

The specifications:

> @EJB Cart cart**1**;
>   @EJB Cart cart**2**;
>   … if  (cart1.equals(cart1))  { //
>   this test must return true  ...}
>   … if  (cart**1**.equals(cart**2**))  { //
>   this test must also return **true**  ...}
>
> The equals method always returns true when used to compare references
>   to the same business interface type of the same stateless session
>   bean.

The specifications cite explicitly the `@EJB` Annotation so I did some tests and I could confirm - `if (cart1.equals(cart2))` **return always `true`** - the identities assumption.

Because very often I see `@Inject` as meant to work the same as `@EJB`, I tried the same example above but with `@Inject`. In that case the `if (cart1.equals(cart2))` **return always `false`**.

I was wondering whether there are some comments on that.

The code for test purposes:

```
public abstract class FormatOutputWithBeansIdentity extends HttpServlet {

    protected void formatOutput(final PrintWriter out, SLSBLocalView beanA, SLSBLocalView beanB) throws IllegalStateException {
        ...;
        out.println("<br>beanA and beanB are equal : " + checkIfEqual(beanA, beanB) + "<br>");
        out.println("<br>beanA and beanA are equal : " + checkIfEqual(beanA, beanA) + "<br>");
    }


    private Boolean checkIfEqual(SLSBLocalView beanA, SLSBLocalView beanB) {
        // The equals method always returns true when used to compare references to the same business interface type of the same stateless session bean.
        return beanA.equals(beanB);
    }
}

@WebServlet(name = "ServletDemo1", urlPatterns = {"/ServletDemo1"})
public class ServletDemo1 extends FormatOutputWithBeansIdentity {

    @EJB
    SLSBLocalView beanA;

    @EJB
    SLSBLocalView beanB;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            ...

            out.println("<h1>Test Session Object Identity Using @EJB</h1>");

            formatOutput(out, beanA, beanB);

            ...
        }
    }
```

}