# Lookup using @EJB fails

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly-10, stateless-session-bean

I'm trying to look up my stateless bean using the annotation class @EJB, but fails. I'm using WildFly 10 as EE container. The stateless bean interface looks as follows:

```
@Local
public interface T1Service {
    String sayHi();
}
```

The implementation class:

```
@Stateless
public class T1ServiceImpl implements T1Service {
    @Override
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi!";
    }
}
```

In my controller I want to inject the service:

```
@EJB(lookup = "javaee/T1ServiceImpl")
private T1Service t1Service;
```

Make the call:

```
t1Service.sayHi();
```

But it fails with a NullPointerException (`t1Service` is null).

What am I missing?

Note, the JNDI bindings are:

```
    java:global/javaee/T1ServiceImpl!p1.T1Service
    java:app/javaee/T1ServiceImpl!p1.T1Service
    java:module/T1ServiceImpl!p1.T1Service
    java:jboss/exported/javaee/T1ServiceImpl!p1.T1Service
    java:global/javaee/T1ServiceImpl
    java:app/javaee/T1ServiceImpl
    java:module/T1ServiceImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller where you want to inject the `T1Service` is also a `@Stateless` Bean? If it is runnning in the same application you can omit the definition of property `lookup`.

I would also suggest to use CDI (`@Inject`) in case that you are using Java EE 6/7/8. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138232/should-i-use-ejb-or-inject) for more information)