# What is the difference between @EJB of JEE and @Autowired of Spring?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, service, annotations, ejb

What is the difference between `@EJB` of **JEE** and `@Autowired` of **Spring** Framework?

- Are those the **same** thing?
- And if not, which are the **differencies**?

I have seen the following as `@EJB`'s definition which really looks like a `@Autowired`'s one:

> An enterprise bean (EJB) is a server-side component that encapsulates
> the business logic of an application.
>
> The business logic is the code that fulfills the purpose of the application. It does not perform
> display of business data or perform operations directly on the database.

Comment: Spring and JEE are competitors. That's why they have some similarities. Usually you pick one or other. Like as when you want one car and need to pick between e.g. Audi or Toyota. Your question is like asking for similarities/differences of Audi and Toyota.

Comment: Hi @BalusC and thanks for the reply. So you mean that they are the same thing or `@EJB` is more general than `@Service` ?

Comment: If you use JEE, then you need `@EJB`. If you use Spring, then you need `@Service`. That's all.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, I have just 100% understood the meaning of your sentences. I was talking about the analogy between them. Based on @Ermal answer, I finally end up to : In Spring: `@Service` is injected via `@Autowired` or `@Inject`. Respectively in JEE, `@Stateless` or `@Statefull` are injected via `@EJB` or `@Inject`.

Comment: Having them mixed in one application indicates a problem though. Use the one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@EJB` is used to inject an **EJB** into another **EJB**, in the **JEE** world.
See: [Should I use @EJB or @Inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138232/should-i-use-ejb-or-inject)

In **Spring** the equivalent injection is done by the use of `@Autowired`.
Example:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

}
@Controller
public class MyController{
    @Autowired MyService myService;
}
```

`@Service` is a **Spring** annotation for annotating a class at a service layer. 
Other annotations: `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Controller`, `@Service`.  
See: [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)

I would say:

- `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` & `@Service` are closer to `@Stateless` or `@Statefull`, and
- `@EJB` is similar to `@Autowired`

**UPDATE**
`@Autowired` tells Spring framework to find dependecies for you. The `@Inject` annotation also serves the same purpose, but the main difference between them is that `@Inject` is a standard annotation for dependency injection and `@Autowired` is spring specific.
See: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/difference-between-autowired-and-inject-annotation-in-spring-framework.html

Comment: Hi @Ermal and thanks for the response.
So in Spring: `@Service` is injected via `@Autowired` or `@Inject`. 
Respectively in JEE, `@Stateless` or `@Statefull` are injected via `@EJB` or `@Inject`. 

This is totally different from @BalusC 's above comments.

Comment: I don't think is the oposite. Seems just a straight forward answer to your question: If you use JEE you need `@EJB`, If you use Spring, then you need `@Service` (and other annotations). EJB and JEE are competitors!

Comment: Ok, I understand that now. The reasoning that the JEE service layer is defined by `@Stateless` or `@Statefull` is right or both of them are too general like `@Component`. In other words is really a `@Service` class similar to `@Stateless` or `@Statefull` class ?

Comment: Hi again @Ermal, do you know if exists any mapper between spring & jee annotations?

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense. Each framework has his annotations to express a specific type inside its semantic domain, but not necessary that type (or same semantic meaning) can be present in the different framework. No mapper needed but you have to rethink all your application architecture.