# Connecting to mysql database as a data source in eclipse web app

Tags: mysql, eclipse, web, jsf

I can connect to the embedded h2 database, but am confused about the correct syntax for connecting to a mysql database named 'test1'.  For example, I would like to know what to substitute in the pom.xml, web.xml and persistence.xml files instead of the h2 terminology.
I'm using mysql 5.7.27, with mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar in my src/main/resources/META-INF/lib folder. My url is jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1

pom.xml - what to use for groupId and artifactId

```xml
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2></artifactId>
     <version>1.4.200</version>
   </dependency>
```

web.xml - what to use for name and class

```xml
   <data-source>
     <name>java:global/DataSourceName>
     <class-name>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</class-name>
     <url>jdbc:h2:mem;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</url>
   </data-source>
```

persistence.xml - does this need to change

```xml
   <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitName" 
     transaction-type="JTA">
     <jta-data-source>java:global/DataSourceName</jta-data-source>
     <properties>
       <property 
          name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
          value="none" />
     </properties>
   </persistence.unit>
  </persistence>
```

Comment: I don't know how to change it, or how it is supposed to look

Comment: Not sure how to fix it

Comment: *"mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar in my src/main/resources/META-INF/lib folder"* where exactly did you read/learn that this would be the correct approach? This misinformation needs to be corrected.

Comment: Not sure, but I've removed this jar file, and added a dependency to the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

follow this [Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586869/how-to-configure-ejb-jpa-in-jta-transaction-mode) to configure all things you need to connect to MySQL or MariaDB.Use the bellow configuration for MySQL.

**- in step (1) use The right classname of MySQl DataSource as bellow:**

```
datasource-classname="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource"
```

Ref: [MySQL Doc - Configuration Properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

**- In step (3) Add this in POM.XML:**

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

Ref: [MySQL Doc - Installing MySQL Connector/J Using Maven](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing-maven.html)

Comment: I have tried to follow your instructions, but I must have misinterpreted something as attempts to run the project result in a 'file not found' message form the browser.

Comment: How to add more information?  The comment section is not long enough.

Comment: try to edit your question to add more information or screenshots.