# why @Inject cannot work but @EJB works in JavaEE 7?

Tags: ejb, java-ee-7, inject

I am going through [JavaEE7-samples](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples) repo in `github`. I found that the author has mentioned the following in this [code snippet](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/blob/master/ejb/stateful/src/main/java/org/javaee7/ejb/stateful/remote/TestServlet.java):

```
// Cannot be injected using @Inject
@EJB Cart bean;
```

The author explicitly mentions that `@Inject` will not work. But I am wondering what is the reason behind it?

I have read the following posts on difference between `@EJB` and `@Inject`. but that did not help me here.

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/inject_vs_ejb

[What is the difference between @Inject and @EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889767/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-ejb)

[Should I use @EJB or @Inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138232/should-i-use-ejb-or-inject)

Answer (score 3):

Both will work if the bean has **Local** interface. However for @Inject to work you have to enable CDI (create beans.xml file in your WEB-INF folder).

If the bean has **Remote** interface you would need to have producer class to declare the resource with the following code:

```
public class RemoteProducer {
    @Produces @EJB
    HelloRemote helloBean;
}
```

For more details see section 3.5 in the [JSR-299 CDI specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/web_beans-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).
So for simplicity of usage I'd suggest to stick with @EJB for EJBs.

Comment: I guess you dont need beans.xml in Java EE 7 container which is what I am using.

Comment: @brainstorm Ahh, you might be right. I've tested it in Java EE 6 container.

Comment: and the javaee7-samples link above is tested against javaee7. so I still don't get the point why @Inject will not work..

Comment: @brainstorm Except beans.xml that can be optional in certain cases in Java EE 7, rest of the answer stands. You can check the CDI 1.1 spec (jsr-346) - For `Remote` EJB you need Producer field or method.